# Spring Boot Actuator - "/shutdown" Fails With 500 Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-applications, spring-boot-actuator

**Background Information**

I have a Spring Boot web application using Actuator for the production utilities.

The application works fine, and the management port works great.  I can browse statistics, check health etc.  I also enabled the remote shut-down endpoint, and it properly shows up in the localhost:{mgmt_port}/actuator list of endpoints.

**My Problem**

When I go to localhost:{mgmt_port}/shutdown though, I see:

```
<Map>
    <timestamp>1453905900007</timestamp>
    <status>500</status>
    <error>Internal Server Error</error>
    <exception>org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException</exception>
    <message>Request method 'GET' not supported</message>
    <path>/shutdown</path>
</Map>
```

**Useful Information**

- The whole application still seems to be running after hitting the shut-down link.  I can still pull data from my custom application endpoints.
- The management URL provided by Spring actuator also seems to still be running fine after hitting shut down.

**Console Output Before Issue**

> 10:01:42.496 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer -
>   Tomcat started on port(s): 8002 (http) 10:01:42.499 [main] INFO 
>   com.xyz.api.Main - Started Main in 5.956 seconds (JVM
>   running for 6.381)

**Console Output After Issue**

> 10:03:29.090 [http-nio-8003-exec-1] INFO 
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring
>   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 10:03:29.090
>   [http-nio-8003-exec-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
>   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
>   10:03:29.126 [http-nio-8003-exec-1] INFO 
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet
>   'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 36 ms 10:03:29.151
>   [http-nio-8003-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] -
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request method 'GET' not supported] with root
>   cause org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
>   Request method 'GET' not supported
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:204)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:382)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:322)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:60)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:351)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration$CompositeHandlerMapping.getHandler(EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration.java:212)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.2.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1120)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_51]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_51]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_51]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question to help others in the future.  I'm a chump... The `/actuator` URL lists all available commands, and all of them work based on a `GET` request.

The `/shutdown` URL actually requires a `HTTP POST` to be sent to it in order to activate it though.  I didn't see this noted anywhere in the docs.

**Sample CURL Command:**

```
> curl -X POST http://hostname:8003/shutdown
```

**Output Of Shutdown Command:**

```
<SingletonMap><message>Shutting down, bye...</message></SingletonMap>
```

Comment: Just hit this too. A 405 or 404 would suit me just fine.

Comment: Yeah that was a little frustrating.  By the way, for other readers, you need "spring-boot-starter-hateoas" on your class-path (or the equivalent pull-ins) to get /actuator to be exposed as a rest-URL.  Otherwise, you just have to know the endpoints off the top of your head and can't get them listed there :(